# Does building a RAM with more storage lead to decrease in performance?

Tags: ram, performance

Talking about Single channel DDR Ram,

If say one RAM module were 4 GB, another 8GB.

Is there any performance difference between those two?

Comment: This is a very broad question because there are many other characteristics that impact performance, and the performance depends on the application. But to answer the question in the title: Generally no.

Comment: There are a lot more specifications on RAM than only the size. This question is very broad.

Comment: Your question is too general and vague. Of course there are performance differences between modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a definitive "maybe, maybe not". It depends on how you design the memory.

For example, if you have a 4GB 32-bit memory module, it would have the same per-bit performance as an 8GB 64-bit memory module. This is because essentially the RAM would be two 4GB devices stuck together. Obviously the throughput for the entire module would be twice as high due to doubling the bus width.

If on the other had you have a 4GB 32-bit memory and an 8GB 32-bit memory, the latter would probably be slightly slower due to the row-column address decoder logic being larger.

I should point out that I haven't considered process variation effects in this. You may find having a larger memory die results in the achievable performance being degraded due to process variation.

You'll find lots of memory frequencies being, not because they are designed for different frequencies, but because process variation during manufacture resulted in some dies being slower than others. Larger dies result in a higher probability of process defects that slow result in the chip having to be run slower.